# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, bigdata

Hi I'm trying to set up Zookeeper server.
I have installed it and am able to start the server but I'm not able to execute the zkCli.sh script. It throws me this error -

```
$ bin/zkCli.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain
```

Can anyone help me out what's going wrong here?

Comment: Seems problem with your Java CLASSPATH, but not sure.

Comment: did you compile the ZooKeeperMain class?

Comment: @Landys The classpath is configured fine.

Comment: @wael No I didn't do that. Is there a need to do so?

Comment: yes try to compile it using javac then try your command

Comment: I'm new to this thing can you help me out?
I dont have a ZooKeeperMain.java file. I just have jars zookeeper-3.4.6 and the set of jars inside lib directory